# How to write data in a text file or modify the contente of text file using angular 4+

Tags: angular

I am trying to read the data from the text file and later on trying to edit the data of that file content. I need the help in writing and modifying the data back in that text file using angular 6

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify a text file located on your filesystem with angular since your code will be run in the browser (frontend) and can't access the filesystem.

You need to create an API that can access the file and do the modifications. Your angular application would then do the modifications to the file by communicating the changes to this API.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. Can you help me with another question. I am using ngModel to update the content of text file I read here. while editing all the content of the files come on same text line. Can you help me out in print those content on the same way as they are mentioned in text file

Comment: @Michael, this looks like a different question, could you write a separate question for it please ? :)

Comment: actually I can ask the next question after 4 days, but this is immediate requirement..If you can help that would be great for  me